# Spring MVC resources path

Tags: spring-mvc

I've got .JSP page with styles set to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/styles/main.css" />
```

It works good for links:

- *localhost/webapp*
- *localhost/webapp/dir*

But when I try "*localhost/webapp/dir/0*" I get an 404 error code.

**servlet-context.xml**:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nickdos answer is right, but I usually resolve this problem differently. You can make use of [BASE tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp). You declare it in head section of every page and all relative links (`<a href>`) and resources (`<script>, <img>, ...`) will be based on this href. So, using EL you can do something like this (sorry, but I can't try it at the moment):

`<base href="${request.scheme}://${request.serverName}:${request.serverPort}${request.contextPath}/" />`

Answer (score 1):

Your path is relative, so if you render your JSP page at a different "depth", the link fails. To avoid this, use a absolute URL path by adding a leading slash. Spring/servlet container can automatically insert the context part of the URL for you, so that the app will work if you deploy it as a "ROOT" webapp. To do this you could use a `<c:url>` tag but I prefer writing one less line of JSP code with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/styles/main.css" />
```